# How to use a picker to add content to my Textview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I wanted to add a drop down box to get the user to select from some pre-defined values in my iPhone app but as that's not possible I thought I would use a picker instead. How do I get the textview to prompt a picker value to populate the Textview with the selection?

Comment: so do you want to write in textview as well as prompt picker, or when exactly do you want to prompt picker?

Comment: No I would like the user to only be able to use the selections in the picker, like you would with a drop down list. Currently as soon as you click in the textview the keyboard comes up instead of the pickerview.

Comment: in - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView method you should return false and call method which shows picker, may be it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a `UIPickerView` as the `inputView` to the `UITextView` and listen for changes to the picker and adjust the content of the `UITextView` accordingly. You will probably still see a cursor though.

The inputView essentially replaces the keyBoard. External keyboard can however still enter normal text into the `UITextView` unless you prevent this via the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to disable the property editing of `Textview`